# How can I organize my folders in Thunderbird?

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird, email-client

This is a current snapshot of my Thunderbird. As you can see folder structure varies between my accounts.

[image]

I'd like to reorganize my accounts' folders such that they look like to my live.com account. My live.com folder structure is exactly what I want, but my first account for example, *Drafts* and *Sent* folders exist inside *inbox* folder, which this doesn't look so good for me. Or in my *Gmail* account what's that magic *[Gmail]* folder? I want to remove it. And finally for my *yahoo* there is no *sent* or *drafts* folder at all.

So my question would be how can I reorganize these folders either in my Thunderbird client or at the server side in order to every accounts look like to my *live.com* account?

Comment: Is your yahoo account a POP or an IMAP account?

Comment: @Slizzered It's of type POP.

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Slizzered Hi, your solution worked perfectly. I'm so sorry, I completely forgot to get back and mark your answer as accepted. Sincerely thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Gmail

go to the account settings for your GMail account, there to
*Server Settings* and click the "Advanced" button. In the field "IMAP server directory", you enter *[Gmail]*.

#### the "other" account

Might work similarly, but instead of [Gmail], try **INBOX.** (the dot at the end might be significant!)

#### Yahoo (POP3)

Since this is not an IMAP account, you don't have access to all the folders that might be available on the server through a webclient. You could create a Sent-Folder and set Thunderbird up to copy every sent email there, but it would still not be synchronized with the *real* sent folder on the server.

The best workaround would be to simply create an IMAP account inside Thunderbird to access your Yahoo stuff and stop using POP3. Of course, this only works if Yahoo actually offers you the possibility to use IMAP.